# Javascript if clause not working properly

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#List').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var lines = $('#List').val().split('\n');
    mylast = lines[lines.length - 1];
    mylen = mylast.length;
    if ((mylen != 8) || (mylen != 4)) {
      lines = lines.slice(lines.length-1);
      $('#List').val(lines.join("\n"));
      alert(mylen);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

But it jumps into the code block after if even if length is 4 or 8....

Where is my error?

I want to remove the last line of the textarea if it's not of a given length.

Comment: You need an AND, replace `||` with `&&`.

Comment: `(mylen != 8) || (mylen != 4)` is true for every conceivable value of `mylen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be:

```
if ((mylen != 8) || (mylen != 4)) {
```

it should be:

```
if ((mylen != 8) && (mylen != 4)) {
```

your way if it was 8 , it was not 4 so it was getting through or if it was 4 it was not 8. you need to check that its not either

Comment: ha no problem, take a 5 min break as well. Don't forget to mark top answer, need my 15 points ha

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if ((mylen != 8) || (mylen != 4)) {
```

means "if length is not 8 **or** length is not 4". So for instance, 4 is not 8, so the condition is true (the second part is never tested, because JavaScript expressions are short-circuited). Similarly, if it's 8, the first part of the expression is false, but the second part (8 != 4) is true, and so the expression is true.

You probably want:

```
if ((mylen != 8) && (mylen != 4)) {
```

`&&` means "and."

Answer (score 0):

Lets examine the case of when `mylen` is `4`.

```
mylen != 8 //true

mylen != 4 //false

true || false // true
```

What you probably want is to prevent `mylen` from being `8` ***and*** prevent `mylen` from being `4`:

```
(mylen != 8) && (mylen != 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's a better version of your code:

```
$('#List').keypress(function (e) {
    var lines, last, valid;

    if (e.which === 13) {
        lines = $(this).val().split('\n');
        last  = lines.pop();
        valid = last.length === 4 || last.length === 8;

        if (!valid) {
            $(this).val(lines.join("\n"));
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

- it declares all variables as local (*never* forget the `var` keyword!)
- it uses `$(this)` instead of repeating the `$('#List')`
- it uses `e.preventDefault()` instead of returning `false`
- it uses a variable named `valid` to transport meaning clearer
- it uses strict comparison (`===`)
- if the code is part of a form validity check, consider putting it into the `submit` event handler instead of capturing the Enter key.